# What is the once listener equivalent in angularfire2?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I was wondering, could we say that:
`this.af.database.object('whatever').first().toPromise()`
is equivalent to :
`firebase.database().ref('whatever').once('value', snapshot=>{})`

I red that firebase caches the data (in memory) for as long as there is an active listener for that data.
So in the case of the once listenner, the data is cleared from the cache. 
Is that the same behavior when I use the first().toPromise(), so does it detached the listenner immediately when the data is received ?

I ask you this question because I often use async and I don't want to lose in performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the answer on [this Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/456#issuecomment-241509299) it seems that `take(1)` will create an observable with `once()`. From there:

> ```
> var team = this.af.database.object('/teams/' , { preserveSnapshot: true }).take(1);
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is that a bad behaviour transforming my observable to promise for the performance of the app ?

Comment: It's hard to give generic advice on performance implications of certain changes. In general I would not try to optimize memory usage (or pretty much anything else) without first measuring what the actual usage is. Once you know that, measuring the impact of the change is fairly simple. But I doubt micromanaging listeners like this is a good way to save memory. I'd sooner look for a way to reduce the amount of data you listen for in general.

Comment: Thank you. Would you recommend me some reading about this subject ( approximate the usage in firebase, performance ...  ) ? I'm new to firebase and I'm still a bit confused about the mechanism behind and so on.

Comment: The easiest way to see what's going on is to look in the Network panel of the developer tools of your browser. You'll find the Firebase Database traffic in the Web Socket (WS on Chrome) sub-panel.

Answer (score 0):

```
async fetchUserRecord(userId: string) {
   const snapshot = await this.firedb.database.ref('users').child(userId).once('value');
   console.log(snapshot.val());
}
```

This is a late answer but, on `angularfire 2`, you can use the above function to query data once and not listen to event or snapshot changes.